# What is the best way to clone a dual booting windows & ubuntu system?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, images, multi-boot, clone

I have a dying hard drive and a replacement drive (same model).  What is the best way to copy the old drive to the new drive?

Its a dual boot setup - Ubuntu Karmic and Windows XP.

I really don't want to have to reinstall both operating systems and all their software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a backup solution which can do **bare metal bit-for-bit backups** of the **entire disk**. [**Clonezilla**](http://clonezilla.org/) is fully capable of this and would be my first choice.

Comment: clonezilla will handle differing disc sizes also. I have yet to encounter a case where it is not better than dd (except where dd is the only option)

Comment: Clonezilla worked beautifully.

Comment: Actually scrap that.  It barfed on the last step of installing grub for some reason.  I've asked about the next step here: http://superuser.com/questions/113938/clonezilla-disk-to-disk-clone-on-a-dual-boot-ubuntu-karmic-xp-setup-cannot-op

Answer (score 5):

If you can plug your new HDD in alongside the old one, you should be able to [clone all the partitions from within Ubuntu using `dd`](http://www.arsgeek.com/2008/01/22/how-to-clone-your-bootable-ubuntu-install-to-another-drive/).  Although the article doesn't mention it, the technique should work for any type of partition as it's doing a raw data copy

Comment: dd is also a great choice. Consider ddrescue as well ( http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue ) which will try harder to rescue the data after read errors.